# Send array from JavaScript to C# .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get an array in my C# backend!
Here's what I am trying....

This is my .aspx page

```
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Save" Style="margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 40%; font-size: x-large; text-decoration-color: grey;" />
    //This is what I am trying to  pass my array in 

    <input id="categoryOrder" type="hidden" value="categoryOrder" runat="server" />
```

Here's my JS

```
    //order is an array that I am trying to get in my c#
    document.getElementById(categoryOrder) = order;
```

Here's my C#

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
 

        if (!IsNullOrDefault(categoryOrder.Value))
            {
            //Menus is type String[]
                Menus =   categoryOrder.Value;
            }
    }
```

In the above code, I get the following error:

> categoryOrder.value is String and cannot be converted to String[]

Things I have tried so far - typecasting, serializing, and deserializing. Nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info.

I am open to trying different methods of passing a JS array to C#. Also, I printed order array in JS and it is correct.

Comment: Your JavaScript assignment statement is flawed. You cannot assign a value to the result of a the getElementByid() method call.

Comment: Mmmm Interesting. Do you know how I can do it then?

Comment: start here: [HTML input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) - to understand that input elements don't hold arrays, only strings - then go here: [JavaScript `.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to understand how the DOM API works.

Comment: Okay1 That makes sense, But this still does not solve my problem of passing the array from js to c# back

Comment: You can't send an array from JavaScript just like you cannot send and Integer or Boolean from JavaScript. This is because Hyper **Text** Transfer Protocol is text based. In JavaScript we serialize those data structures using the [JSON API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) (a JavaScript array is a type of Object in JavaScript that can be serialized)

Comment: Well! I guess then I will just try to stringify the array and then split it!